# Big curl_multi requests or multiple little curl requests (php)

Tags: php, curl, optimization, php-curl, curl-multi

I have to update 106600 data using a REST API but I don't know the most optimized way to do this.

The main difficulty is that the API return data 100 per 100 and I must use offset to have all them all (1066 API calls).

After that, I have to retrieve extra data for each off these data. It mean 1066 other calls and one again to update it (thanks to php multi_curl functions).

My question is : **As I know how many items I have, Should I use php multi_curl functions for the first call too, to have 106600 data in one call ? And maybe do the same for the two new calls to do only 3 calls ?**

---

I mean if the API send me only packages of 100 elements each time, it should be for a good reason.

Will the server support this kind of request ?

We have limited API calls (I don't know the exact number) and the company make calls everyday to work. I'm trying to find a solution to not paralyze my company.

---

Should I use my actual script and find a way to update data gradually ?

If I find the number of calls and if it's enough should I go ahead ?

Or should I prepare a big request to get and update all data with a minimum of calls ? (If it's possible it will be only 3 calls, that would be great ^^)

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand the question. But I would worry that if I made 1066 call using multi_curl the the site would get overloaded and quite possibly ban my IP address from making calls completely. Do the other site not suggest how to best make 1000's of calls to their site without causing them issues?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think number of calls will not be a problem. One time I used up all calls because of an infinite loop and I just stopped it and ask to double the calls allowed (I always pay attention to that now ^^). It's a partner (not just a service I found) so I think I can ask them. Is, getting data at one time, good for performance (For client machine and service server) ?